# Click on a link under td/td section selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm reading a table from a web page and one of the columns has a link in it. The table is something like this:

```
</div>
<div class="separator"></div>
<h1>User Management:</h1>
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         ...
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Johnny@gmail.com</td>
         <td>Johnny</td>
         <td><a class="pointer" onclick="deleteUs('http://localhost/..');">button1</a>
            |<a class="pointer" onclick="resetPas('http://localhost/..');">button2</a>
            |<a href="http://localhost/something/something">button3</a>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      </tr>`
```

I want to click on button3(which is found in each row in this table) which gets the page redirects to the mentioned href(http://localhost/something/something)
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example to click on the link of the row having the cell "Johnny" :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[td='Johnny']//a[@href]").click()
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try with find_element_by_partial_link_text() method.

```
    element = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Jhonny')
```

Hope it helps.

Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table//td//a[@class!='pointer']"))
select.click()
```

or

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table//td//a[3]"))
select.click()
```

Comment: because the table is dynamic I want to use the specific href. Is there another way to do this using the href?